# remove and addchild button in as3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to click on the button "choose1" then button will disappear and the next is to add a button.
I would like to make two requests in a click event of the button "choose1".

EDIT: this is my code

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class Bo extends MovieClip
{

    var choose1:Choose;



    public function Bo()
    {
        // constructor code
        choose1=new Choose();
        addChild(choose1);
        choose1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickChoose);
    }

    function clickChoose(e:MouseEvent):void
    {


        for (var i:Number=stage.numChildren -1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            stage.removeChildAt(i);
            //stage.getChildAt(i).visible = false;
        }

        var ex:Next=new Next();// add new button
        addChild(ex);
        //this.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickChoose);
    }


}
```

anyone can help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing a button after click is bad UX, consider adding whichever button you want but keeping the old one.

Comment: I've tried to hide the button and add a new button, but the button does not appear.
"stage.getChildAt (i). visible = false;"

Comment: Btw, it is also a bad habit to use lowercase name for class name. Your  for loop is also strange, why do you need to have two conditions about i?

Comment: I had to edit the code for easy view. About loop "for" I do not find it unusual at all. Thanks